# Signup flow with advanced navigation example

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-navigation

I am currently using bottom navigation like in [navigation advanced example](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/master/NavigationAdvancedSample), I am trying direct user to signup flow if user is not authenticated. I use following code in side defaultly selected fragment to direct user to sign up flow (login_nav_graph) if they are not authenticated.

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)


        if(!authenticated){
            view.findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_frag1Fragment_to_login_nav_graph)
        }
    }
```

But there are few problems

- Shows back button when user in signup flow
- Bottom navigation is shown in signup flow

These problems make sense, Reasons:

- since signup flow (`login_nav_graph`) is nested inside bottom navs first items(defaultly selected) navigation graph.
- Bottom nav is on `activity_main` layout.

So **how could I integrate signup flow into navigation advanced example and overcome above mentioned issues with a better approach?**

Note:

code is very similar to navigation advanced example, I introduced separate nav graph for signup flow called `login_nav_graph` and above mentioned code in defautly selected fragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the issue by doing following.

1. Add `login_nav_graph` to the nav graph which contains defaultly selected fragment as a nested nav graph.
2. Create an `action/path` from defaultly selected fragment (`frag1Fragment`) to the `login_nav_graph` and set the `Pop To` behavior of the action to the `frag1Fragment`'s nav graph.
3. Create following two methods inside the `MainActivity` in order to toggle the visibility of the action bar and bottom nav.

   ```
   fun toggleBottomNavVisibility(){

       if(bottom_nav.visibility == View.VISIBLE){
           bottom_nav.visibility = View.GONE
       }else{
           bottom_nav.visibility = View.VISIBLE
       }
   }
   ```

...

```
fun toggleActionBarVisibility(){

        if(supportActionBar!!.isShowing){
            supportActionBar?.hide()
        }
        else{
            supportActionBar?.show()
        }
}
```

4. Update the `onViewCreated` method of the `frag1Fragment` as follows

...

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    if(!authenticated){

        // hide bottom navigation and action bar
        val activity = activity as MainActivity
        activity.toggleBottomNavVisibility()
        activity.toggleActionBarVisibility()

       findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_frag1Fragment_to_login_nav_graph)
    }
}
```